# Wordpress form submission is shows error. how to solve that?

Tags: php, html, forms, wordpress

Hi i am developing a WordPress plugin.. this is my shortcode.php file.

It shows form correctly. but form submission is not working.. after form submission it shows page not found error.

```
 <?php
    //shortcode [my_table id=""]
    function custom_table_shortcode($atts)
    {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'id'=>''       
        ), $atts));
     ob_start();
     global $wpdb;  
     if(isset($_POST['insert'])) 
   {
        $from="doNotReply@widdle.com";
        $check1=$_POST['check1'];
        $check2=$_POST['check2'];
        $check3=$_POST['check3'];

        mail("talon77email@talon77.com", "Form Submission Notice", $check1 , "From: $from");
        print "Your form has been submitted";
    }



    ?>
<form id="twform" action="#" method="post">
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check1" />Print Design
<input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check2"/>Logo Design
<input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check3"/>Web Design
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="insert"> 
</form>
    <?php return ob_get_clean();
    }
    ?>
```

I dont know how to solve that problem.. please any one help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your **action="#"** with..

```
action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

I have faced the same issue bofore... let me know this helps you or not...

Comment: @Boopathi does mails are getting sent?? I mean is your form submitting?

Comment: does not get the value

Comment: @Boopathi try putting a static path in form action.. like `action = "localhost/wordpress/form"` and check what it does..

Comment: @Boopathi and which you provided in the question is the whole form? if not please provide the whole form...

Comment: @Boopathi is it whole form you provide in this question??

Comment: @Boopathi how do come to the chat??

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
<form id="twform" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
```